# Ruby on Rails Sql transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

I am wondering if there is a better way to manage transactions with Ruby on rails than attaching it to the class model ?

```
Student.transaction do
  Course.transaction do
    course.enroll(student)
    student.units += course.units
  end
end
```

I don't want my transactions to be model specific, so that I can begin/commit/rollback them genericly at the controller level with no model dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`.

AFAIK there is no difference at all. Opening a transaction with one of your models does not limit the usage of different objects not belonging to this model within the transaction at all.

See here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i should read more carefuly next time :)